# How can this XSL be refactored to take advantage of apply-templates?

Tags: xslt

Taking this [question about beautiful XSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506348/how-do-i-know-my-xsl-is-efficient-and-beautiful) but getting more specific, how should I refactor this XSL to take advantage of apply-templates and/or keys.

I tend to "over use" for-each elements to control the context of the source and I can imagine that apply-templates can help. Despite much Google-ing, I still don't understand how to control context within the multiple templates.

In the below example, how can the repetitive XPath segments be reduced by refactoring?

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="Body">
        <xsl:element name="Person">
            <xsl:if     test="/source/dbSrc/srv/v[@name='name']/text()='false'">
                <xsl:element name="PhoneNumber" />
                <xsl:element name="Zip">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="/source/req[1]/personal-info/address-info/zip-code" />

                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="/source/dbSrc/srv/v[@name='name']/text()='true'">
                <xsl:element name="PhoneNumber" />
                <xsl:element name="Zip">
                    <xsl:value-of select="/source/req[3]/personal-info/address-info/zip-code" />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:element>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This code sample is quite hard to understand without a sample of XML data wich is being processed.

Comment: Please update your post to include both input and output sample XML

Comment: @vbence I can do that tomorrow. Thanks.  In the meantime, the goal is to select a grandchild based on the value of a cousin.  I'll edit in the mean time to make simpler.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two possible refactorings :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One initial way of refactoring the given code would be the following:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <Body>
   <Person>
    <PhoneNumber/>
     <Zip>
       <xsl:apply-templates select=
        "/*/dbSrc/srv/v[@name='name']"/>
     </Zip>
   </Person>
  </Body>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="v[@name='name' and .='true']">
   <xsl:value-of select=
   "/*/req[3]/personal-info/address-info/zip-code"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="v[@name='name' and .='false']">
   <xsl:value-of select=
   "/*/req[1]/personal-info/address-info/zip-code"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Do note**: The refactored code doesn't contain any conditional xslt instructions.

**Further refactoring can let us get rid of the last too templates**, because in this case additional templates aren't actually needed -- the code only creates a single element and depends on a single condition:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:variable name="vCond" select=
  "/*/dbSrc/srv/v[@name='name']/text()='true'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vInd" select=
  "3*$vCond + 1*not($vCond)"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <Body>
   <Person>
    <PhoneNumber/>
     <Zip>
      <xsl:value-of select=
      "/*/req[position()=$vInd]
                /personal-info/address-info/zip-code"/>
     </Zip>
   </Person>
  </Body>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**: Here we assume that `/*/dbSrc/srv/v[@name='name']/text()` can have only two possible values: `'true'` or `'false'`

Comment: +1 Thanks.  The first XSL helps clarify that (1) the template match XPATH is applied to a node set specified in the apply-templates select attribute and (2) the selects have access to the full document.

Comment: In the first XSL, it seems that a latter-added apply-template would unintentionally invoke the existing templates.  For example if apply-templates select="/*/dft/value[2]/v[@name='name']" were added to the root template, I expect that an existing "v[@name='name']" template would be applied.  Is there a best practice to ensure that the secondary templates are only applied to a single apply-template location?

Comment: @David-W: One can specify more context in the match pattern. Also, the predicate(s) can be made as specific as needed.

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 2.0 I would write this as:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Body>
        <Person>
          <PhoneNumber/>
          <Zip>
            <xsl:variable name="index" as="xs:integer"
               select="if (/source/dbSrc/srv/v[@name='name']='true') then 3 else 1"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="/source/req[$index]/personal-info/address-info/zip-code"/>
          </Zip>
        </Person>
    </Body>
</xsl:template>
```

With 1.0, the xsl:variable becomes a bit more complicated but otherwise it's the same.

Note the use of literal result elements and variables to reduce the size of the code; also the avoidance of "/text()", which is nearly always bad practice.

There's very little mileage in using template rules here because you're using so little of the input data, and because you seem to know exactly where to find it. Template rules would come into their own if you wanted to be less rigid about knowing exactly where you are looking in the source: they help to make code more resilient to variability and change in the input. But without seeing the source and knowing more of the background, we can't tell you where that flexibility is needed. The hard-coding of the indexes "1" and "3" looks like a danger signal to me, but only you can judge that.